# Runtime Error 1004 MDeterm Property

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this function to calculate the area of a polygon.  For some reasons, when my last value in the `DataRange(4) = 0`, I am getting **#VALUE!** in the excel sheet.

On the code side, the part, `X3 = WorksheetFunction.MDeterm(array3)`, is getting:

> runtime error 1004: Unable to get MDeterm Property in the immediate
>   windows.

Error Screenshot

[image]

```
Public Function polygon(DataRange As Variant)
    Dim Area As Variant
    Dim X1 As Double
    Dim X2 As Double
    Dim X3 As Double
    Dim X4 As Double

    Dim array1(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim array2(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim array3(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim array4(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant

    array1(1, 1) = 0
    array1(1, 2) = DataRange(1)
    array1(2, 1) = DataRange(2)
    array1(2, 2) = 0

    array2(1, 1) = DataRange(2)
    array2(1, 2) = 0
    array2(2, 1) = 0
    array2(2, 2) = -(DataRange(3))

    array3(1, 1) = 0
    array3(1, 2) = -(DataRange(3))
    array3(2, 1) = -(DataRange(4))
    array3(2, 2) = 0

    array4(1, 1) = -(DataRange(4))
    array4(1, 2) = 0
    array4(2, 1) = 0
    array4(2, 2) = DataRange(1)

    X1 = WorksheetFunction.MDeterm(array1)
    X2 = WorksheetFunction.MDeterm(array2)
    X3 = WorksheetFunction.MDeterm(array3)
    X4 = WorksheetFunction.MDeterm(array4)



    Area = Abs(0.5 * (X1 + X2 + X3 + X4))
    polygon = Area

End Function
```

Comment: You're going to have to post more code; i.e. `MDeterm` and perhaps `DataRange`; you have not provided us with enough information to help you answer your question.

Comment: What's in array3 when it fails?

Comment: you are getting this error on the code side precisely because the function returns `#Value` in the excel sheet. in order to solve your VBA error you have to figure out why you are getting `#Value` in the sheet. 99% you have an extra space in one of the cells or they are formatted as text.

Comment: Thanks Banana, but I have specifically defined the dimension of my array.  I have also add Option Base 1 just to make sure that I am not adding extra space to the cell.  I am still getting the #Value! on my excel sheet.

Again, I am only getting #Value! for DataRange(4) = 0 and I am only getting an error on X3 in the immediate windows.

Comment: Hi Tim, 

array3 is 0 and there were no problems getting the values into the array3.  As long as DataRange(4) = 0, there will be a #VALUE! error on the excel sheet.  I expect the answer to be 0.  When I debug the problem, X3 got the runtime error.

array3(1, 1) = 0
array3(1, 2) = 0
array3(2, 1) = 0
array3(2, 2) = 0

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with feeding a 2x2 array of zeros to that function:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim arr(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
    arr(1, 1) = 0
    arr(1, 2) = 0
    arr(2, 1) = 0
    arr(2, 2) = 0

    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.MDeterm(arr) '>> 0

End Sub
```

Something else is going on in your case. Declaring your arrays as a numeric type instead of variant might help to track down the issue.